# Php get Navigation

Tags: php

Hie

I use the GET method for navigation on one of my websites. The problem is that some dirty Einstein has create a link that calls another domain:

http://www.mywebsite.com?products=http://www.dirtyeinstein.com?fishform.inc

Is there a script that i can use to block this kind of abuse.

Thank you.

Comment: What are you doing with the GET variable? Putting it into `file_get_contents` or `include`/`require`, or a redirect?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

simply check in your script if the requested page exists, like

```
// allowed get parameters for product
$whiteList = array(
   'tvs',
   'toys',
);

$menu = $_GET['products'];

if (! in_array($menu, $whiteList) {
   // forward to inde
} else {
  // forward to requested page
}
```

Comment: Whitelisting shouldn't even be needed, a simple `file_exists()` or `is_file()` should do the trick, though it may depend on your server's settings.

Comment: @Duroth that's not true, the URI can be parsed to call a function or anything else in addition to purely include a file by it's complete name.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using navigation like that?

http://www.mywebsite.com?products=book.php

If you are not redirecting anyone out, I mean if you don't use something like

http://www.mywebsite.com?products=http://www.myanotherdomain.com

Then just check the string if it starts with "http"

May help: http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Ex:

```
$str = $_GET['products'];
if (strlen($str) > 4 && if (substr($str, 0, 4) == "http")
{
   echo "You dirty Einstein!! Get out!";
   return;
}
```

Comment: You'd also need to check if it starts with ftp, rss, ssl or any other protocol, so this isn't really a solution

Comment: This is the wrong solution, the only safe way is to check against a whitelist, not to exclude based on rules.

Comment: blacklisting never works in such scenarios. better use a whitelist of  allowed  pages (see ArneRie’s answer)

Comment: thanks guys, all your responses have been useful - keep coding!